# How to extract transactional details from text file if multiple transaction data are given

Tags: python-3.x

·        ALERT:You've spent Rs.2.00 via Debit Card xx2217 at AMAZON PAY INDIA PRIVA on 2021-03-25:02:10:37.Avl Bal Rs.1091.07.Not you?Call 18002586161.

```
                                      Aggregate under bank withdrawal
```

·        ALERT:You've withdrawn Rs.500.00 via Debit Card xx1135 at +UBI NOIDA MAIN on 2021-06-06:20:27:20.Avl Bal Rs.854.14.Not you?Call 18002586161.

```
                                              Aggregate under UPI
```

·        HDFC Bank: Rs 1.00 debited from a/c **1135 on 06-08-21 to VPA kshreyansnahar@okhdfcbank (UPI Ref No 121554846690). Not you? Call on 18002586161 to report

```
                                            Aggregate under food
```

·        Rs.327.25 on Zomato charged via Simpl.

Food, groceries, commute, or medicines. Buy Now, Pay Later via Simpl. Know More:    https://app.getsimpl.com/Jrf0zPQaFt- Simpl Pay

·        Payment of Rs. 370.6 using OlaMoney Postpaid for your transaction fzip-ndco-5wbi on Zomato is successful. Not you? Write to us at support@olamoney.com

```
                                               Aggregate under credit applications
```

·        HDFC Bank: Rs 393.66 debited from a/c **1135 on 20-07-21 to VPA simpl@axb(UPI Ref No 140653242517). Not you? Call on 18002586161 to report

·        HDFC Bank: Rs 145.60 debited from a/c **1135 on 28-06-21 to VPA olamoney.payu@indus(UPI Ref No 117914757648). Not

Comment: Hi. Your question is not clear...

Comment: actually i want to scrape data from a link https://docs.google.com/document/d/14s1DiPiTfe1SgApAD7m2gH_qzM04YMpRUyGOOXzjhgk/edit

Comment: and aggregate transactional details

Comment: the question is not clear. Can you give the expected output ?

Comment: I want to extract transactional details from the given Google doc link</n>just help me scrape the text want to make data into tabular form columns represent bank, UPI, credit application, food and rows as values provided